# Upvoting my own answer without flag privilege downvotes the answer

Tags: bug, voting, up-votes

As the title states, if one does not have the rep to upvote and attempts to upvote their own answer, it results in a net -1 to the answer score and a -2 to the user's rep.
I suspect this is caused by the upvote being undone once because of the lack of privilege and again for it being one's own question.

I suspect this also happens with voting on questions, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: Can you link to the answer you downvoted?

Comment: Looking through all (1) of your posts, I don't see any with downvotes.

Comment: Or somebody else downvoted at the same time...

Comment: @mhlester - He only has one answer and it sits at +1 right now. It is a decent answer, please no one metattack it.

Comment: @TravisJ could have been deleted? OP needs to confirm

Comment: I had deleted that answer because it was a bad one. Is there anywhere I can post an answer to demonstrate this?

Comment: @mhlester - Ah, good call.

Comment: @jus1in - In your recent answers, under profile activity, there should be a link for recently deleted answers.

Comment: @jus1in - [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3396937/jus1in?tab=answers&sort=newest), at the bottom of the list of answers.

Comment: @jus1in - See if you can share the link.

Comment: @TravisJ I can't see the answer there. I believe it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922123/need-help-regarding-my-project-in-java/29922277?noredirect=1#comment47965777_29922277) but that just 404's because the question was deleted as well.

Comment: @jus1in - That link worked :) I can see deleted posts on SO due to reasons

Comment: It's a non-answer, it has 4 downvotes.  Looks like you just got downvoted at the same time as you upvoted yourself and assumed it was a bug.

Comment: @jus1in - That answer sits at -4, it was a good choice to delete it, and I don't think that you downvoting or upvoting it caused any of those votes. You may also want to delete this post :P As it will probably be closed as no repro. I think your observance was just coincidence.

Comment: @TravisJ I guess so. I guess attempting to upvote updated the votes, and it was coincidence that they happened the same time twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is how things happened. Maybe you just misunderstood what actually happened.

I think that while you were trying / testing how the voting works on your own answer, you were down-voted.

A down-vote on your question or answer results in a -1 for your post score, and a -2 for your reputation.

Comment: This seems likely. I had attempted to upvote twice with the same effect, so I assumed it was my actions. I guess it was just a coincidence.